# How to create a login for Facebook or Google popup home page in magento 1.8.1?

Tags: magento-1.8, php, mysql

How do I create a login for Facebook or Google popup home page in magento 1.8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a login functionallity with facebook and google popup, add its html in home page via CMS block, write jquery to to open popup on document.ready of home page.

Comment: how to call app\design\frontend\default\default\template\ma2_popuplogin\popuplogin.phtml url in cms block?

Comment: i tried this code but not working{{block template="frontend/base/default/template/asktologin/index.phtml"}}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of these and find the best way for creating extension by your own:

[Facebook Login](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-login-4.html)

[Facebook Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-connect-1.html)

[Facebook All](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-all.html)

[Facebook Signup / Facebook Login widget](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-signup-facebook-login-widget.html)

Comment: Hi serge i am asking for creating myself not using any extensions or modules thanks for your suggesion